# Laravel 6 policies authorizeReosurce

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

Estoy usando las policies en laravel, inyectado **$this->authorizeResource()** me ahorro tener que hacerle individual para cada metodo pero me sale unauthorized cuando accedo al metodo show

[image: Esta es la politica para poder ver un recurso, incluso la forze a true]
Esta es la politica que incluso la force a true

[image: este es mi controlador]
mi controlador
[image: el metodo que me devuelve el objeto]
el metodo para mostrar el recurso

[image: si borro $**this->authorizeResource()** de mi constructor y utilizo esta sintaxis me funciona bien, pero no quiero hacer $this->authorize cada vez que lo necesite]Aqui me funciona bien

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en que la policy está esperando un objeto de la clase `Driver` pero lo que le llega es el `id` (lo que está como parámetro en `show()`).

Entiendo que tenés 2 opciones:

**Primera opción:**
Reemplazar el parámetro `Driver $driver` de la policy por `$id` y ocuparte manualmente de obtener el objeto (como mostraste en tu ejemplo).

```php
public function view(User $user, $id)
{
    $driver = Driver::findOrFail($id);
    ...
}
```

---

**Segunda opción:**
Probablemente lo que te convenga es usar [implicit binding](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#implicit-binding). Vas a tener que reemplazar en tus rutas los parámetros `{id}` por el nombre de la clase (en singular y tiene que ser igual al nombre de la variable que está en el parámetro del controlador):

```php
Route::get('drivers/{driver}', 'DriverController@show')->name('drivers.show');
```

Y lo mismo en los controladores:

```php
public function show(Driver $driver)
{
    return $driver;
}
```

De ésta manera Laravel resuelve el modelo automáticamente, no hace falta que lo resuelvas vos. Si por algún motivo querés resolverlo de una manera distinta, podés utilizar [explicit binding](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#explicit-binding).

Probablemente te venga bien leer sobre [resource controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#resource-controllers).

PD: Por favor editá tu pregunta y reemplazá las imágenes por texto. Las imágenes dificultan la lectura, no se pueden copiar para responder, los motores de búsqueda no las indexan, etc, etc.